# Magento 1.9 - get product attribute on checkout for sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, product-attribute

I want to store an attribute value as an order comment when an order is placed.

Here is my code:

```
class Easylife_Meta_Model_Observer
{
    public function autocomment($observer)
    {
        $_product->getProduct();
        $comment = $_product->getDeliveryTime();
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment( $comment, false);
        $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to get order in observer, from order object you can get all items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public function getAttr($observer)
{
    //Get quote item
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $quoteItem = $event->getQuoteItem();
    // get product attributes from $quoteItem
    $_options = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getData('your-attribute');
}
```

Or if the above code doesn't work then you can change Magento event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` instead of `sales_order_place_after`.